# How to ignore an element and scroll an element behind it

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs

Is there any way to "ignore" an overlay element and scroll an element behind it? Or scroll a different element when you are "scrolling" (or really, activating the wheel event as the overlay won't be scrolling). I am trying to create a box that has content you can scroll, but I also need to style it some. I don't think I can just style the elements as I want the styling to remain static and not scroll with the scrolled content or even have to switch off classnames based on an "active" scrolled element because I want the styling to stay static over the options.

See more here: https://codepen.io/lmsutter/pen/eYrLWpp

```
function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <div className="scrollWrapper">
        <div className="overlay">
          <div className="opacity"></div>
          <div className="opacity"></div>
          <div className="border"></div>
          <div className="opacity"></div>
          <div className="opacity"></div>
        </div>
        <div className="scrollContainer">
          <div className="option">option</div>
          <div className="option">option</div>
          <div className="option">option</div>
          <div className="option">option</div>
          <div className="option">option</div>
          <div className="option">option</div>
          <div className="option">option</div>
          <div className="option">option</div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

It is in React so I do need a react solution. Thank you for your time reading This.

Comment: you can add `pointer-events: none` to the element to ignore.

Comment: If the overlay element is not meant to be intractable by the pointer, then try `pointer-events: none`

Comment: That worked! Can't believe I struggled for so long on that. I knew that was property but didn't know it would apply here since it was scroll and not a click. Thank you both!